# Obtener OUTPUT de procedimiento y guardar en un txt

Tags: c#, sql

Pueden ayudarme el resultado de un `output` guardarlo en un .txt usando C# y
SQL

**SQLServer**

```
create table Dedito
(
ruc nvarchar(11),
nom varchar(max),
asd varchar(max),
ddd varchar(max)
)
go
insert into Dedito values('20532803749','danilo','Computadora','FLD_25')
insert into Dedito values('20543433459','Lucero','mochila','FLD_30')
insert into Dedito values('24555523449','Keymi','zapato','FLD_2')
insert into Dedito values('29999663196','CAmila','cuaderno','FLD_15')
insert into Dedito values('20947646732','Diana','lapicero','FLD_77')
select  * from Dedito

create procedure prueba
@aa varchar(max) output
as
begin

select (ruc) +'|'+(ddd) from Dedito
end

DECLARE @aa VARCHAR(max)
EXEC [dbo].[prueba] @aa output
print @aa

--Resultado
--20947646732|FLD_77
```

**C#**

```
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.125.55;Initial Catalog=pp1;user id=sa;password=***********;");
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("prueba", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("D:/DD/path.txt", true);
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(row["aa"].ToString());
        }
writer.Close();
        connection.Close();
```

Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el código de tu SP y explica mejor lo que quieres lograr con tu procedimiento.

Comment: ya lo edite victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `Stored Procedure` te funciona de esa manera?, porque veo que te va a devolver múltiples resultados y tienes solo una variable de salida tipo `VARCHAR`. No se que es lo que realmente quieres hacer, pero la respuesta a tu pregunta es esta:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("prueba", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@aa", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1));
command.Parameters["@aa"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
connection.Open();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(
    @"C:\path.txt", 
    command.Parameters["@aa"].Value.ToString()
    );
connection.Close();
```

Lo que yo te recomendaría es solo tomar el `SELECT` y recorrerlo desde la aplicación utilizando la lógica que quieres usar en el `Stored Procedure`.

El problema lo tienes en que no estas asignándole el valor a la variable que vas a devolver dentro del **SP**:

```
create procedure prueba
    @aa varchar(max) output
as
begin
    select @aa = (ruc) +'|'+(ddd) from Dedito
end
```

Ahora según lo que yo veo lo que quieres hacer es obtener el valor de todos los registros y concatenarlos de esa manera que indicas, para lo que yo recomiendo que lo hagas así:

```
create procedure prueba
as
begin
    select (ruc) +'|'+(ddd) AS 'aa' from Dedito
end
```

Y en **C#** colocar esto:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Con);
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("prueba", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\path.txt", true);
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    writer.WriteLine(row["aa"].ToString());
}
writer.Close();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Gracias un duda mas podria poner ejm el nombre de txt de un campo o varios campos de mi tabla? ejm nombre+telefono.txt 
Saludos

Comment: acabo de poner el codigo me sale el siguiente error(editare la pregunta)

Comment: Revisa ahora a ver si te funciona no le asignabas ningún valor a la variable

Comment: ya salio falto agregar  writer.Close(); para terminar

Comment: si ya lo revise acabo de editar jaja pequeño error